# git bash doesn't like one folder

Tags: bash, git

I've got a command-line tool called SFDX in a folder called "Salesforce CLI". The executable is in the path.  I can run it from cmd.exe but can't from git bash.  It also is not found by Visual Studio Code if that's a clue.

Let me copy in some output.

**cmd.exe**

```
>path
[...]C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;[...]C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
>sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/6.11.0-9a1ef8794d (windows-x64) node-v8.9.4
```

Now in **git bash**

```
$ echo $PATH
[...]/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_162/bin:[...]/c/Program Files/Salesforce CLI/bin
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_162"
$ sfdx --version
The system cannot find the path specified.
$ ls /c/Program\ Files/Salesforce\ CLI/bin -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 taude 197610 121 Apr  9 20:15 sfdx*
-rw-r--r-- 1 taude 197610 824 Apr  9 20:15 sfdx.cmd
$ /c/Program\ Files/Salesforce\ CLI/bin/sfdx --version
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The only thing that catches my eye is some double semicolons in my DOS path.  But those don't show up as double colons in git bash.  I'm kinda freaked out.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you specify the absolute path to an executable then `$PATH` is irrelevant.

Comment: Does your `PATH` end with a DOS carriage return, by any chance? `cat -v <<<"$PATH"` (and more generally take care to use quotes around your variables unless you know exactly what you are doing).

Comment: I seem to recall that `cmd` will attempt to run the file based on `PATHEXT`, meaning it will probably get `sfdx.cmd`. Git Bash will probably go straight to the `sfdx` file. Might be worth looking in to that. What happens if you copy `sfdx` to `sfdx99` and try to run `sfdx99` from `cmd`?

Answer (score 0):

Try first in CMD to make sfdx work with the minimal PATH possible (smallest set of folders needed), including:

- `Salesforce CLI/bin` in first
- `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` in last.
- `D:\prgs\git\latest\bin;D:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin` in the middle

Then open a git bash and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I think @paxdiablo is on the right track. I see there is a known limitation of this particular command line tool in that it does not support tools like git bash.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204932/i-am-trying-to-login-to-sfdx-sample-devhub-using-git-bash-its-giving-an-error?rq=1

If I try to run sfdx.cmd instead of sfdx it works.  This doesn't solve my real problem that VS Code is not finding it but I'm progressing.